# Can't see "My Music" albums on iPad after resubscribing to Apple Music

Tags: itunes, ipad, apple-music

I haven't been subscribed to Apple Music for one month. Today I have subscribed back. I used iTunes on Mac to do that.

Immediately all my "Apple Music" albums on a Mac returned. They also showed on an iPhone. But not on iPad.

Apple Music is working on iPad, but I just don't see any of the albums I saved for later in "My Music" section. I tried signing out and in and restarting the device. Still none of the albums are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning on 'iCloud Music Library' in Settings solved the problem.